# Link a stylesheet file in android

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my android phone,

when I copy my simple project that includes just a html and css file to my android phone and when I open it, I see the css file doesn't work!!! it works perfectly in computer but in androind colors, font size, font familes and other styles. I don't mean resposive. I mean that I think the link property doesn't work

I tried many codes

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>css</title>
<link href="./app.css" />
  </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the browser what the [external resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) is by adding attributes to the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css" />`

Comment: thank you, I tried that but it didn't work too

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yoursite.com/app.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: thanks. but I wanted to open it on my local Android phone

Comment: Try: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css" type="text/css" />